# different Data Sheet View and Standard View

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to have different views for Data sheet view and standard view. I mean wehen you go to Data Sheet view you see another columns than you see in standard view.?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ but yes, all views are configurable to have whatever columns you want in them.